# How to parse a PDF with Python?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I am trying to read a PDF with Python. [Here](http://www.copyright.gov//onlinesp/agents/h/hosting_services_inc_amd.pdf) is a link for PDF.

When I make it with slate, first line goes like r: _H_o_st_in_g_S_e_rv_ic_es_ln but it must be like "Hosting Services Ink". Can it be fixed programmatically?

Here is how I do this one:

```
doc = slate.PDF(fp)
            file = open('temp.txt', 'w')
            file.write(doc[0].encode('utf-8'))
            print 'wrote'
```

Comment: you can remove all underscores from a string with `'___example___'.replace('_', '')`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with the following code:

```
import re

s = '_H_o_st_in_g_S_e_rv_ic_es_In_c'
s = s.strip('_')
res = s[0]

for c in s.split('_')[1:]:
    if c:
        if re.match('[A-Z]', c):
            res = res + ' ' + c
        else:
            res = res + c
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
'Hosting Services Inc'
```

Comment: The question is more global. I mean can i get something like fixer for text like this. It can be for example not one underscore but two or three. Or it can be random. As i understood this is related to pdf document. But your answer is good. Thanks :)

Comment: For the whole pdf file you may need to look for some library, I do not think that this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not, or at least not perfectly.  You can take an input string `_H_o_st_in_g_S_e_rv_ic_es_ln`, remove all underscores and put spaces in front of capital letters fairly easily. But it looks like the text you're getting is not necessarily the correct text, which may effect your outputs.

```
def add_space(st):
    out = []
    for ch in st:
       if ch.isupper():
           out.append(' ')
       out.append(ch)
    return ''.join(out)

print(add_space('_H_o_st_in_g_S_e_rv_ic_es_ln'.replace('_', '')))
```

outputs

```
Hosting Servicesln
```

because your character recognition software sees the `Inc` as `ln`